# jQuery how to do action on click a button which is inside HTML Iframe?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

Guys i'm trying to create a simple script with jQuery where on clicking a button inside an html iframe it's making action on the main page.

Here is my iframe code:

```
<iframe src="http://beta.sportsdirect.bg/checkout/onepage/" id="inneriframe" scrolling="no" target="_parent"></iframe>
```

Inside thi html iframe i have a button with id "billing-buttons-container"

My question is how i can get the click on button inside the iframe and then do some function in the main page ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are they both on the same domain? If not, you may have to do some reverse proxy trickery.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the iframe you can call a parent js function using `parent`:

```
<a onclick="parent.functionName();" href="#" > linkToParent </a>
```

Comment: I don't need that. I need a method which is tracking a click inside the iframe itself. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @user2942786 If I understand your question correctly, then this solution will work for you. The `<a>` element needs to be placed inside the iframed page.

Comment: `functionName` needs to be defined in the main page, as `window.functionName = function(){/*stuff*/}`

Comment: user2942786 if you don't own the iFrame src, then I don't think it's possible to catch the click event, if that is what you are saying you want. I just don't know how to doit.

If, you own the iframe, as @ArturoTorresSánchez indicated, you can use my code inside the iframe and define the function on the parent page so you can execute changes to the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in the `onload` method of your iframe.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('inneriframe');
var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow;
if (typeof doc.addEventListener !== undefined) {
      doc.addEventListener("click", function(event) {console.log('clicked');}, false)
} else if (typeof doc.attachEvent !== undefined) {
      doc.attachEvent("onclick", function(event) {console.log('clicked');});
}
```